# How to search makers in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, searchview

I need help. My code have about 1200 markers. I want to search for markers from FloatingSearchView, I tried many ways but still could not find the markers .
My code  :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {  // Hien thi ra giao dien
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// hien thi noi dung
        pdLoading.dismiss();  // khi tai du lieu xong thi ngat thong bao

        try {
            JSONArray mangJson = new JSONArray(s);
            List<Marker> list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mangJson.length(); i++) {
                lat = mangJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat");
                long1 = mangJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("long1");
                matram=mangJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("matram");
                tthuyen=mangJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("tthuyen1");
                glat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                glong1 = Double.parseDouble(long1);
               glatLng = new LatLng(glat, glong1);
               Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(glatLng).title(matram)
                       .snippet(tthuyen)
                       .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
              marker.showInfoWindow();


                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(glatLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 14));
                // Them nhung marker nay vao mang Marker
                list.add(marker);
           //     mang2.put(matram, marker);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

fuction filter :

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
   // Log.w("search", charText);
//  mMap.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {

    }
    else
    {


        for (Marker  m : list) {
            if (m.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {

           //     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(glatLng));

               // mProductList.add(wp);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
  //notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I need help, can you help me?
Thanks you?

my logs:

```
05-14 23:02:18.397 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.Animator$AnimatorPauseListener', referenced from method com.bartoszlipinski.viewpropertyobjectanimator.ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.get
05-14 23:02:18.397 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 12 (Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorPauseListener;) in Lcom/bartoszlipinski/viewpropertyobjectanimator/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator;
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00b5
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/view/View;.TRANSLATION_Z
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 9784 (TRANSLATION_Z) in Landroid/view/View;
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/view/View;.TRANSLATION_Z
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 9784 (TRANSLATION_Z) in Landroid/view/View;
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/view/View;.Z
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 9787 (Z) in Landroid/view/View;
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/view/View;.Z
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 9787 (Z) in Landroid/view/View;
05-14 23:02:18.409 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
05-14 23:02:23.461 3714-3717/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 10620K, 20% free 44937K/55676K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 39ms
05-14 23:02:31.465 3714-3714/net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: please add some logs in which you logged the values all over your code

Comment: as Masoud says, u need some logs in the filtering process at least, that will show title & charText, why they are not matching, you may need to use `trim()`  ? or it could be anything else